# onChange triggers on every keystroke

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I have a `onChange` event attribute in an input box in a component,

```
<input
    type="text"
    required
    className="form-control"
    onChange={this.onChangeUsername}
/>
```

which is handled by this `onChangeUsername()` function

```
onChangeUsername(e) {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    this.setState({
      username: e.target.value,
    });
}
```

this function is called on every keystroke. Why is that?

[image]

Comment: Interesting, that's not true when using raw HTML/JS but it does happen in a very simple React app. https://stackblitz.com/edit/input-change-event-react?file=index.js Notice the correct behavior on https://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/zL3uy80e/1/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

React's `onChange` does not behave like the native [HTML change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) event. It behaves more like the [input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event). If you want to be notified after the user has left the field, the suggestion is to use `onBlur`.

See https://linguinecode.com/post/onblur-vs-onchange-react-text-inputs and [React and text inputs - use onBlur or onChange?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52509068/react-and-text-inputs-use-onblur-or-onchange)

Answer (score 0):

Because of `onChange` event. As it sounds, every changes apply to that input will trigger function `onChangeUsername`

Comment: onChange should trigger once it looses focus on that element right?

Comment: That's `onBlur`.

Comment: change is supposed to fire after the user leaves the field. https://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/zL3uy80e/1/ See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event  `For some elements, including <input type="text">, the change event doesn't fire until the control loses focus. Try entering something into the field below, and then click somewhere else to trigger the event.`